# remove index.php of the url 1and1 with codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Hi I have a problem in removing the index.php from the url through htaccess 1and1, I have tried several examples of other threads but did not work either.
The htaccess if I 'running on localhost is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|css|resources|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help.

1. Check whether **`mod_rewrite`** is enabled.
2. Remove **`index.php`** from **`config.php`**

   ```
   //$config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; //old line

   $config['index_page'] = ''; // New line
   ```
3. Add below code in the **`.htaccess`**

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
   ```

Comment: I have the same. I need to check mod_rewrite. How do I check mod_rewrite?

Comment: echo phpinfo(); 

Check "mod_rewrite" in Loaded modules.

Answer (score 0):

For the last line try using

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```